# Twilio responds with in-progress without the status being requested?

Tags: c#, twilio, webhooks, twilio-api

I'm trying to fix an issue, we're getting an `in-progress` call status as a result the `Dial` verb, which in this case should only occur when star is pressed.

However, the action is called regardless of whether star is pressed. In this scenario we have music playing and therefore genuinely the call is `in-progress`.

I thought we would only get these extra states if we requested them via a callback.

```
<Response>
    <Say language="en-GB" voice="woman">Welcome person....</Say>
    <Dial callerId="record-from-answer" record="record-from-answer" hangupOnStar="true" 
        action="http://ourserver/handler">
        <Conference beep="false" startConferenceOnEnter="true" muted="false" 
             waitUrl="http://com.twilio.music.classical.s3.amazonaws.com/ClockworkWaltz.mp3" 
             waitMethod="GET">57354</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Intermittently Twilio doesn't respond the Twiml passed to it in this instance, but it waits till star is actually pressed. I believe in some scenarios the call status must be `completed` and the correct Twiml is then processed.

The goal here is to only use the action if star is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Dial action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus) fires when the dialed party hangs-up or is hung-up on or doesn't answer (which won't happen here since you dialing into a conference). So you will see the action URL fire, when * is pressed since you are using the dial attribute, hangupOnStar="true" BUT you will also see the action URL fire when the dial party manually disconnects from the conference (without pressing star). The [DialCallStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus) provides the details of the Dial.

I don't follow your statement, "intermittently Twilio doesn't respond to the Twiml passed to it in this instance". The TwiML should comes from your application server, located at: http://ourserver/handler. You can look at the Twilio [Request Inspector](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136407-Debugging-your-application) to see why TwiML may not be returned by your Application Server.

Comment: There is a CallStatus key and a DialCallStatus key. The CallStatus key is the leg of the call that initially entered Twilio (the side you are then trying to dial into the conference) and the DialCallStatus is the status of a call made (into the conference) using the Dial Verb, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#callstatus-values. Under your Twilio number set-up (where you set-up webhooks), do you also have "Call Status Changes" populated with the same statusCallback URL (which appears under your Twilio Number) / https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming?